# How to not be able to jump while sliding and not be able to slide while jumping? Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity 2D, and I'm working on a sliding mechanic. but the only problem is, is that I can jump while sliding and I can slide while jumping. How can I make it so that u cant jump while sliding and slide while jumping?

I have a character controller from Brackeys, with some code removed that makes it possible to crouch. Here is the character controller script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = true;                  
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                         
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; 
    public bool m_Grounded;            
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    public bool m_FacingRight = true; 
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]

    public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (OnLandEvent == null)
            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                m_Grounded = true;
                if (!wasGrounded)
                    OnLandEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Move(float move, bool jump)
    {
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
        }
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
    }


    public void Flip()
    {
        if (!gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().isWallSliding)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().wallJumpDirection *= -1;

            m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }
}
```

With the character controller script, I also have a player movement script also by Brackeys (I think). Here it is:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Wall Sliding")]

    [SerializeField] private float wallSlideSpeed = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform wallCheckPoint;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 wallCheckSize;

    private bool isTouchingWall;
    public bool isWallSliding;
    private const float wallCheckRadius = 0.2f;

    [Header("Wall Jumping")]

    [SerializeField] private float wallJumpForce = 18f;
    [SerializeField] public float wallJumpDirection = -1f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 wallJumpAngle;

    [Header("Player Components")]

    [SerializeField] private CharacterController2D controller;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject wallCheck;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D regularBoxColl;
    [SerializeField] private CircleCollider2D regularCircleColl;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D slideColl;

    [Header("Running & Jumping")]

    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed = 40f;
    [SerializeField] private float horizontalMove = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private bool jump = false;

    [Header("Sliding")]

    [SerializeField] private float slideSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private bool isSliding = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        wallJumpAngle.Normalize();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        WorldCheck();
        WallSlide();
        WallJump();

        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            PreformSlide();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, jump);
        jump = false;
    }

    private void PreformSlide()
    {
        isSliding = true;

        animator.SetBool("IsSliding", true);

        regularBoxColl.enabled = false;
        regularCircleColl.enabled = false;
        slideColl.enabled = true;

        if(!controller.m_FacingRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * slideSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * slideSpeed);
        }

        StartCoroutine("StopSlide");
    }

    IEnumerator StopSlide()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.75f);
        animator.SetBool("IsSliding", false);

        regularBoxColl.enabled = true;
        regularCircleColl.enabled = true;
        slideColl.enabled = false;

        isSliding = false;
    }

    private void WorldCheck()
    {
        isTouchingWall = Physics2D.OverlapBox(wallCheckPoint.position, wallCheckSize, 0, wallLayer);
    }

    private void WallSlide()
    {
        if(isTouchingWall && !controller.m_Grounded && rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsWallSliding", true);
            isWallSliding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsWallSliding", false);
            isWallSliding = false;
        }

        if(isWallSliding)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, wallSlideSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void WallJump()
    {
        if (isWallSliding && isTouchingWall && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(wallJumpForce * wallJumpDirection * wallJumpAngle.x, wallJumpForce * wallJumpAngle.y), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            animator.SetBool("IsWallSliding", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsWallJumping", true);

            StartCoroutine(EndWallJump());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator EndWallJump()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        controller.Flip();
        animator.SetBool("IsWallJumping", false);
    }

    public void OnLanding()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(wallCheckPoint.position, wallCheckSize);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already have according bool flags so simply check them like e.g.

```
if (!animator.GetBool("isSliding") && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
```

and

```
if(!animator.GetBool("IsJumping") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
```

Comment: Now, I can't jump while sliding but i can still slide while jumping. How could I fix this?

Comment: You would probably not do `animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);` until you are actually grounded again and not Everytime you are not pressing the jump button ... something like `else if(characterController.m_Grounded){ animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false); }`

Comment: Oops, my bad, the player isn't actually sliding while jumping. This is actually what happens: when you jump, it plays the jump animation unless you press left shift while jumping. I think that's the best way I can explain it. Sorry!

Comment: how could I stop the slide animation from running when I jump? as explained in the last comment. I tried quite a lot of ways to prevent it from happening but I couldn't figure it out. Sorry for bothering you!